# Quickly selecting last n records from mysql database os size 700Mb

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0

I'm developing an application wherein I've to display the last n records based on the user input. The queries run good when the records are less. But as the records grow it takes a lot of time to get the records, which in-turn is affecting my UI. So i wanna ask is that is there any better way to get the records quickly from DB. I already have a PK column & the table has 26 columns.

Thanks,
Karthick V

Answer (score 0):

Use **Indexing** for your table fields for fetching data fast.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-indexes.htm

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx

http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-indexes-sql-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the last records inserted from a single table, without heed to any other values, then `ORDER BY <PRIMARYKEY> DESC LIMIT <N>`
should do the trick, provided you  make an auto increment primary key. `Order by ... desc` means descending order.

```
SELECT <columns> FROM <table> order by <idfield> desc limit <n>
```

If you have multiple tables being joined together, then `alter table add index (<column>)` on the columns used for joins to make the searching and joining process faster.